Why N is their only model (up to isomorphism) in peano system?
Definiton(Natural number set):
The set $N$ is nonempty. $0 \in N$, $S:N \to N$, if they meet the following condition:

$S$ is injection , i.e. $S(y_1) = S(y_2) \Rightarrow y_1=y_2$
$0 \notin S(N)$
$N = \{0\} \cup S(N)$
$M$ is a subset of $N$, if $0\in M$, and $\forall_{x \in M}(S(x) \in M)$ then $M = {N}$.

then we call $(N, S, 0)$ a natural number set.
My teacher or some books about set theory said that any two natural number sets satisfy the following theorem, so they are equivalent or isomorphic.
Theorem
$(N_1, S_1, 0_1)$ and $(N_2, S_2, 0_2)$ is two natural number sets, then there is a unique bijection $f: N_1 \to N_2$ satisfies

$f(0_1) = 0_2$
$\forall_{x \in N_1} f(S_1(x)) = S_2(f(x))$

Commutative diagrams:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
N_1 @>S_1>> N_1\\
@V f V V @VV f V\\
N_2 @>>S_2> N_2
\end{CD}
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
x @>S_1>> S_1(x)\\
@V f V V @VV f V\\
f(x) @>>S_2> f(S_1(x))=S_2(f(x))
\end{CD}
I can understand why this theorem is correct.
But I can't understand why this theorem implies that the two natural number sets are equivalent or isomorphic.
Why is the definition of two natural number sets isomorphic or equivalent like this?
I know there's the concept of isomorphism in group theory, but natural numbers are not groups. Does the isomorphism here have relationship with the isomorphism in group theory?

Too long for a comment:
One way of thinking about isomorphisms is that they involve renaming objects without affecting their (relevant) properties. A group isomorphism renames the elements of a group. One way of thinking about the isomorphism of natural numbers is that the numbers used in England are essentially the same as those used in France, Japan, China ... even though each country names them differently. All sorts of mathematical objects have isomorphisms - the point is that the (relevant) mathematical structure is preserved, so that the mathematical consequences are the same. It does not matter which language we count in, the outcome is equivalent.
Sometimes the following interesting situation occurs, which may take some thought, but is worth thinking about: as additive groups the integers $\mathbb Z$ are isomorphic to the even integers $2\mathbb Z$ via the mapping $z\to 2z$. However, this isomorphism of groups does not preserve multiplication - it is not a ring isomorphism.
[A ring is a mathematical structure with two operations, normally called multiplication and addition, which have defined properties that we expect of multiplication and addition and their interaction]
